# LVM - pvmove to a smaller volume

Tags: linux, lvm, arch-linux, pvmove

I would like to `pvmove` a logical volume to a smaller, but faster drive, leaving the excess part on the original drive. Can that be easily accomplished?

Comment: Please tag your question with the operating system you are using. Probably Linux, but NetBSD or HP-UX can also have a pvmove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my understanding is that if you add additional PV (physical volume) to a VG (volume group) that hosts your LV (logical volume) you should be able to issue pvmove like so:

```
# Move a range of physical extents to a
#       specific PV (which must  have  suffi‐
#       cient free extents).
       pvmove /dev/sdb1:1000-1999 /dev/sdc1
```

taken from `man pvmove`

Comment: Ranges are what I've been looking for. Thank you!